# Display search results from API

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Hello there I'm trying to create an app to search for recipes. I've tried using the Yummly API and BigOven api, but I can't get either to work.

here is the code i have for bigOven. I can't get any search results to appear in the  "results".

```
$(function() {
    $('#searchform').submit(function() {
        var searchterms = $("#searchterms").val();
        // call our search twitter function
        getResultsFromYouTube(searchterms);
        return false;
    });
});

function getResultsFromYouTube (searchterms) {
    var apiKey = "dvxveCJB1QugC806d29k1cE6x23Nt64O";
        var titleKeyword = "lasagna";
        var url = "http://api.bigoven.com/recipes?pg=1&rpp=25&title_kw="+ searchterms + "&api_key="+apiKey;


        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            url: url,
            success: function (data) {
                alert('success');
                console.log(data);
                $("#results").html(data);
            }
        });
    }
```

Can anyone give me instructions on how to do this?? Thank you very much.

Comment: Are you sure you can use pure JSON with these APIs and not just JSONP?

Comment: i'n very, very, very inexperienced in thie field, so not sure. but this is what the documentation says:

The BigOven Recipe API currently supports two serialization formats: XML (Extensible Markup Language), and JSON (JavaScript Object Notation).
Requesting a Serialization Format

The API uses the HTTP "Accept" header of the request in order to determine the serialization format of the returned data.
Serialization Format  HTTP Accept Header
XML  text/xml
JSON  application/json
EXAMPLE TO FETCH JSON (JQUERY)

Comment: Your request is working and returning an object. http://jsfiddle.net/jayblanchard/2E9jb/ Now all we need to do is parse that object.

Answer (score 0):

The API is returning JSON data, not HTML. I checked the API docs, and JSONP isn't necessary.

However, when you run this code:

```
$('#results').html(data);
```

Your code is going to just put the JSON into your HTML, and that isn't going to get displayed properly. You didn't say whether `console.log(data)` outputs the data correctly, but I'll assume it is.

So, you'll need to transform your JSON into HTML. You can do that programmatically, or you can use a templating language. There are a number of options, including underscore, jquery, mustache and handlebars.

I recommend handlebars, but it's not a straightforward bit of code to add (the main difficulty will be loading your template, or including it in your build).

http://handlebarsjs.com/

Answer (score 0):

It would depend on you which key and values you have to show to your user's and in which manner... For ex. there is even an image link, you could either show that image to your user's or could just show them the image link...

<kbd>***[Simple `<p>` structure of all the key's with there value's](http://jsfiddle.net/NPMg7/1/)***</kbd>
***jQuery***

```
$.each(data.Results, function (key, value) {
    $.each(value, function (key, value) {
         $("#result").append('<p>Key:-' + key + ' Value:-' + value + '</p>');
    });
$("#result").append('<hr/>');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your ajax is working, you just need to parse the results.  To get you started:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    url: url,
    success: function (data) {

        // Parse the  data:
        var resultsString = "";
        for (var i in data.Results){
            console.log( data.Results[i] );
            resultsString+= "<div>"+data.Results[i].Title+ " ("+data.Results[i].Cuisine+")</div>";
        }
        $("#results").html(resultsString);

    // If you want to see the raw JSON displayed on the webpage, use this instead:
    //$("#results").html(  JSON.stringify(data) );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had created a little recursive function that iterates through JSON and spits out all of the values (I subbed my output for yours in the else condition) -

```
function propertyTest(currentObject, key) {
    for (var property in currentObject) {
        if (typeof currentObject[property] === "object") {
            propertyTest(currentObject[property], property);
        } else {
           $('#results').append(property + ' -- ' + currentObject[property] + '<br />');
        }
    }
}
```

Then I called it within your AJAX success -

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    url: url,
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        propertyTest(data); // called the function
    }
});
```

It spits out all of the data in the JSON as seen here - http://jsfiddle.net/jayblanchard/2E9jb/3/